# styling action bar use a Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android

I am following the android training , in styling the Action bar.

I am facing error because of `android:theme=@style/MyActionBar`.

I want to know how to style the action bar.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyActionBar" >
```

> IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme with
>   this activity

I thought the error from :

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
               parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        </style>
```

so I modify it to

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light ">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

I had the following error :

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light '.

I created a new file as the training explained

res/values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->

    <style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#aaaaaa</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/MyActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.helloworld.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.Helloworld.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.Helloworld.MyActivity" />
    </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you added the library into project properties?

Answer (score 4):

edit your style as follows:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

for support library you have to use

```
name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

instead of

```
name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

and then use this theme in your manifest...
before use don't forget to add support:appcompact dependencies in build.gradle if you are using Android Studio...
thanks...

Answer (score 2):

`appcompat v7` libary has two kinds of files. One is `jar`, the other is `res`es like `string.xml` `styles.xml`. You question implies that you didn't import `res`es of `appcompat` library. So, import the project of `.../Android-SDK/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` into your Eclipse, and then add it as a libary project of your main project.

Comment: how to import the library ? I read 'suppoert library Features' in android site but I didnt know how to import it

Comment: In your `Eclipse`, `File`-->`Import`-->`Android`-->`Existing Android Code into Workspace`-->`Next`-->`Browse`-->then select `.../Android-SDK/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`-->`OK`-->`Finish`.

Comment: when I arrived to Existing Android code into workspace .. it was empty , I searched for my project and I add it , I still not able to click insert , Btw I noticed in eclipse above my project there is appcompat_v7 @silentKnight

Comment: Don't you find the folder of `.../Android-SDK/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`? If no, you need to download from `Android Manager`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added a reference of appcompat lib in your project. Add the reference of it to your project and check

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: I have the latest library installed Rev 22